# How to disable a submit button in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable or hide a button using jquery after the form has been submitted. I have tried some solutions but nothing happened.. I have included js file in my page.

Here is my submit button code:

```
 echo '<td>
           <a href="shortlist.php?vid='.$row["v_id"].'&uid='.$row["userid"].'"">
               <input type="submit" value="short list" id="shortlist" name="shortlist">
           </a>
       </td>';
```

Here is my jQuery code.....

```
$('input:submit').click( function() {
    console.log("Form is submiting.....");
    $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `type` attribute.

Basically apart from class and id selectors, `CSS2` selectors are also supported by `jQuery`.

```
$('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", true);
```

> [att=val] Match when the element's "att" attribute value is exactly
>   "val".

[Reference:](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

You can create form submit event to achieve that,

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

And then just set disabled attribute for input with submit type.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `type` attribute and need to set the `disabled` attribute to 'disabled'

```
$('input[type=submit').click(function(){
    console.log("Form is submiting.....");
    $('input:submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery code after click submit button, it will disable.

```
$('input[type=submit').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Form is submiting.....");
            $('#shortlist').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
```